# Python: Ignoring empty lines when identifying happy numbers

Tags: python

The task (from codeeval) is to read a file that has a few different numbers, and print 1 if it is a happy number or print 0 if it is not a happy number. Part of the task is to ignore the item (`num`) if it is an empty line. Here is my code:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for num in test_cases:
    if num=="":
        pass
    else:
        liszt=[]
        while num>1:
            newnum=str(num)
            total=0
            for i in newnum:
                total+=int(i)**2
            if total not in liszt:
                liszt.append(total)
                num=total
            else:
                print 0
                break
        else:
            print 1
test_cases.close()
```

I get an error message that references the `total+=int(i)**2` line, saying this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Which makes me think I'm not being successful in ignoring empty lines. Am I on the right track? If so, what change should I make to the code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you want `continue` instead of `pass`.

Comment: Simply `print num` and see what's going on...

Comment: @squiguy Both will do the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure you don't deal with empty lines and new lines, you can simply add:

```
if num.strip():
    num = num.rstrip('\n')

    # DO SOMETHING HERE...
    # ...
```

So you'll get:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for num in test_cases:
    if num.strip():
        num = num.rstrip('\n')

        # DO SOMETHING HERE...
        # ...

test_cases.close()
```

Comment: It would be more elegant to do `if num.strip():`

Comment: @alfasin: Yeah you're right :). Took it into consideration for the PO ;)

Comment: stripping twice is a bad idea. `strip` once and check if the stripped string is valid.